# How can I programmatically prevent the PC connected to a handheld device from file syncing (grabbing files from the device)?

Tags: synchronization, filesystems, windows-ce, activesync, handheld

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328063/which-branches-of-the-registry-does-a-ce-device-read), I added code to my handheld app to (attempt to) prevent certain types of files (by extension) from being synced to the PC. But this doesn't work if the user, on the PC, uses ActiveStync to enable file sharing. On doing so, regardless of handheld registry settings, it copies files from the handheld to the PC (from the handheld's `\My Documents` folder to the PC's `C:\Users\clay\Documents\Documents on Clay's Device` folder).

Is there a way to programmatically prevent (on the `handheld/Windows` CE side) this syncing from taking place? Or is it just a matter of the user reaping what they sow when they select file syncronization?

### UPDATE

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350937/why-does-the-handheld-device-ignore-the-filesyncpath-registry-keys-value) (I'm not completely preventing syncing, but I'm preventing the syncing of the files that I don't want to have synced, by making sure that the `FileSyncPath` registry key does not match where I am saving the data in question).

Comment: It has been a while since my handheld dev days so not posting an answer. But IIRC we had similar issues and we decided to go with [OpenNetCF's RAPI](https://rapi.codeplex.com/). Activesync was giving us too many problems and with above library we had fine grained control on what exactly we need to pickup from the device and what to ignore. HTH